# Contact Form 7 Conditional fields with auto filling field

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, contact-form-7

How to show conditional calculation in contact form 7 ?

For Example:
i have a form with two field such as **student number** and **payment amount**.

**one student fee is $10.**

so if user entering student count in the first field need to display student fee automatically into the payment field.

that is if student count is 2, then the second field want to display amount as $20.

its possible in contact form 7 plugin?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with jquery. For example cf7 shortcode like this

```
[text* qty id:qty ]
[text* price id:price readonly]  (Readonly for not editable fields)
[text subtotal id:total class:total readonly]
```

jquery code: (Include in separate js file)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var qty=$("#qty");
    qty.keyup(function(){
        var total=isNaN(parseInt(qty.val() $("#price").val())) ? 0 :
        $(qty.val() $("#price").val())
        $("#total").val(total);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ugPxf/

[contact form 7 backend screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39bnt.png)

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for sharing your idea. but its not working with contact form 7.. i have created a template page and added js cdn followed by html, js code snippet and working fine. but if i have adding the short code of contact form 7 will not respond.

Comment: Please check your contact form 7 id.I already used this feature in one of my website (It's like qty and unit price calculation) and it's working fine.Refer the screenshot attached.